Get Q values in Stable-baseline3 callback
Is there a way to access the q values/mean- q value in a DQN using Stable baseline3? This doesnt work and I cant seem to find a way written in the docs or a way I can implement this given im new to this.
    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
    # Perform the check at specified frequency
    if self.n_calls % self.check_freq == 0:
        if 'new_obs' in self.locals:
            new_obs = self.locals['new_obs']
            if isinstance(new_obs, dict):
                new_obs = new_obs['observation']
            
            # Process the observation
            observation = new_obs.reshape((-1,) + self.model.observation_space.shape)
            observation = th.as_tensor(observation, dtype=th.float32, device=self.model.device)
            with th.no_grad():
                q_values = self.model.policy.q_net(observation)
            mean_q_value = q_values.mean().item()
            self.mean_q_values.append(mean_q_value)

        # Collect rewards from the info buffer
        if len(self.model.ep_info_buffer) > 0:
            self.rewards.append(np.mean([ep_info['r'] for ep_info in self.model.ep_info_buffer]))
            self.epsilons.append(self.model.exploration_rate)

    return True

The above seems to be running and returning values, just not sure if this is the correct way to obtain it. Must be a more straight forward way?
